# The code validator not passing my input tag

Tags: html

Here is my html:

```
<input type="text" name= "favoritemovie"><br/>
```

Any idea what this warning means in the code validator? : You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".

Comment: Excellent; thank you for the quick and accurate response; just starting with php, stilling learning the basics

Comment: It’s an explanation to an error message, not a warning.

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says it means.  Your input tag isn't closed.  Use `/>` at the end of the tag, just as you have with your line break.

```
<input type="text" name="favoritemovie" /><br />
```

With XHTML, all of your tags must be closed.

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines there should be a space in `<br/>`, namely `<br />`. On the other hand, if an HTML 4.01 or HTML5 doctype is declared instead of an XHTML doctype, the “self-closing” slash is not needed.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, Space added.  I didn't realize that was part of the guidelines... good to know!  Yes, with HTML you don't technically need this, which is why I noted that the rule was for XHTML.